# Java Class.forName().newInstance() method creates instance of stale Java class

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, liferay-6

I'm developing an enterprise project with Liferay 6.1 EE and tomcat 6. Coding is in local PC, but deploy to a CentOS virtual machine.

There's a custom `.jar` file to handle some special logic with URL redirecting. After I modified a Java class, recompile and built the new `.jar`, replaced the existing `.jar` file on the vm. (located in `{$tomcat}/lib/ext` and `{$tomcat}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`) and restarted tomcat, I found it was still using the previous code logic. I'm sure that the `.jar` file was updated on VM (grabbed from VM, and decompiled the `.class`, the code was there)

This class is instantiated by Class.forName().newInstance method, and put to a static final map in another custom filter.

Clearing `{$tomcat}/temp` and `{$tomcat}/work` folders didn't help, is it possible that this stale class is cached in JVM ? If yes how can I remove the stale content ?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: No, the JVM doesn't cache classes.

Comment: Attention: You should not add the same class to `/lib/ext` and `/webapps`, as this will lead to class incompatibilities. And as Andreas said: no, there is no cache by the JVM. You should check your `webapps` and  `libs` directory, that no other JAR or the `classes` directory contains the old class file.